# Performance Concerns between DataTable and SqlDataReader to fill Data with FlexGrid

Tags: vb.net, datatable, sqldatareader

Which one is more faster between DataTable and SqlDataReader while I'm trying to fill Data into FlexGrid with VB.NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what are you trying to do, if you just need to get x rows then Reader would be faster but if you will manipulate or want to use caching for result set then go for Data collection of any kind.

Answer (score 1):

SqlDataReader is faster as it is readonly forward only. However DataTable is xml based and is slower.

Answer (score 1):

SqlDataReader is much faster. 
It is readonly and you can only forward run on it.

I use readers all the time unless it's an emergency...